# Get ffmpeg source code at a specific revision

Tags: git, ffmpeg, revision

I know how to do it with SVN, but they've moved to Git.

The command for getting the newest version as described on their site is

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
```

What would be the appropriate arguments for getting a specific revision?

Comment: Why do you need a specific version? Developers are very interested in regressions if you are experiencing a bug. Bug reports for such things are appreciated.

Comment: The current version ffmpeg is creating a h264 file that's unplayable on my phone, but it used to work with older versions. Now that I think about it, it might be a regression in libx264, too.

Comment: I bet you just need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, but if you want more than a guess then I recommend making a question on superuser.com and include your command and the complete console output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cloned repository run:

```
git checkout <hash>
```

To return to the master branch run:

```
git checkout master
```

To find a particular hash you can use:

```
git log
```

or [browse FFmpeg commits online](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git).

Comment: What is this hash? Is it like a revision number in SVN?

Comment: @satuon: Yes.  Every git commit is uniquely identified by its SHA-1 hash.

Comment: OK, thanks. Those commands, do I execute them after `git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`? Also, what should be the working directory?

Comment: @satuon Yes, you need to clone the repository first as shown with your command. The working directory will be the resulting ffmpeg directory.

Comment: Yes; in the `ffmpeg` directory (the git repo)